# change logo and hide global navigation for only one page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, global-navigation, site-logo, hide-elements

I have requirement to change the logo and hide Global navigation from One page of SharePoint 2013 environment.

have any one tried it before!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a Script Editor webpart to the page with the following snippets:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ms-breadcrumb-top {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ms-siteicon-img').attr('src', '<your logo url>');
    });
</script>
```

You can use *#DeltaTopNavigation* or *#sideNavBox* instead of *.ms-breadcrumb-top*.

If  you have not jQuery on the page, you can add the cdn script link at the top of the snippet webpart content:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**: As @Danny '365CSI' Engelman suggested, a solution without jQuery may be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeLogo() {
        document.querySelector('.ms-siteicon-img').setAttribute('src‌​', '<your logo url>');
    }

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(changeLogo);
    }, "sp.js");

</script>
```

Comment: Note: the *no-jQuery-needed; I can do it with vanilla JavaScript* way is: ``document.querySelector('.ms-siteicon-img').setAttribute('src', '<your logo url>');`` .... **but** ... it requires less typing